# How did Samantha Carter walk through the Stargate from SGC to Atlantis

Tags: stargate

Did they use the gate macro thing, or did they have a ZPM? If they used the gate macro with a mid-point, would they suffocate in space?

Comment: It might help to mention which episode you're talking about :)

Comment: nevermind.. im guessing they finished Midway Space station at that point, episode I am talking about is when SAM became the leader of Atlantis Expedition.

Answer (score 12):

The McKay/Carter Intergalactic Gate Bridge consisted of 34 gates placed at even intervals between the Milky Way galaxy and the Pegasus galaxy. When something was sent through the Earth gate it was dematerialized and sent onto the next gate's buffer, which in turn sent the dematerialized person or supplies onto the next gate without materializing. This was made possible by a macro written by McKay, which overrode the normal operation of the gates. The reason for this setup was because intergalactic distances were well outside the operational range of a normal gate.

The Midway Space Station was just the midway point on the bridge. It was useful as a security checkpoint in case the Earth or Atlantis gates were compromised, and was the only point on the 34 gate journey were something was materialized.

And yes, Carter became the commander of the Atlantis expedition in 2007 (Episode Reunion S04E03) and the Bridge was operational in 2006

Comment: Copy paste? wait a moment, so is this confirming that the midway space station is already functioning?

Comment: @Sid I don't understand what you mean by copy paste? And I don't know if the Midway space station was working by Reunion, but I do know that the bridge was working by then. They are two different things :)

Comment: and my question was How did Samantha Carter walked thru the Stargate from SGC to Atlantis. it is possible if you were in a puddle jumper. but walking?

Comment: @Sid well that's what I'm answering. The Bridge allows you to walk through because you never materialize along the way, you are just sent as energy from one gate to another all the way to Atlantis (or the Midway space station, if you decide to stop there).

Comment: oh... so you can go directly from 1 point without going to the mid point??

Comment: You pass through all the points, you simply don't materialize, you are buffered and passed to the next gate in the chain, each gate acting more as a temporary storage unit until the next gate has been programmed to receive and send.